# are these statements the same?

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory

If I show this statement:

$$x\in \left] a,b \right[ \Rightarrow \exists n \in \mathbb{N} :  x\in \left] -\frac1{n}, 1+\frac1{n}\right[$$

Have I then shown this statement:

$$]a,b[ \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left] -\frac1{n}, 1+\frac1{n}\right[\qquad ?$$

Comment: Yes. And conversely if you have proved the second, you have proved the first.  Whether the two statements are "the same" is a more complicated matter.  It all depends on the exact *definitions* that have been given for $\subseteq$, for $\cup_{n=1}^\infty$, and so on.  The two statements are likely *not* the same, though they certainly are equivalent.

Comment: What do the opposite brackets mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

- A set $A$ is a subset of a set $B$ if and only if $x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$.
- If we have $A_i$ then $x\in\bigcup A_i$ if and only if for some $i$ we have $x\in A_i$.

Combine the two result and you have indeed what you wanted.

Note, while at it, that $(-1,2)$ which is the interval for $n=1$ (since $-\frac{1}{1}=-1,\ 1+\frac{1}{1}=2$) is a superset of all the other intervals. In particular this whole union is just $(-1,2)$ to begin with.

Comment: Actually, as the supremum of each interval is $1+1/n$, not $1/n$, the entire union is $(-1, 2)$, not $(-1, 1)$.

Comment: @jwodder: Thanks for the correction.